# Datagrid doesn't show older data

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 datagrids. ultraGrid1 and ultraGrid2.

Ultragrid1 has newest values and Ultragrid2 has older Ultragrid1 values.

However, It always shows the same newest data not older one.

```
public void getAllTopActivityData()
{
    dtTopAllTemp.Clear();                    // Clear the all rows before new values 

    odagetTopAllTemp = new OracleDataAdapter(getTopAll, oradb);
    odagetTopAllTemp.Fill(dtTopAllTemp);     // get new rows 

    ultraGrid1.DataSource = dtTopAllTemp;    // Shows new rows
    ultraGrid2.DataSource = dtTopAllTempOld; // Shows older rows

    dtTopAllTempOld = dtTopAllTemp;          // Set Older rows to the datatable 
}
```

Comment: Try debugging that function - and pausing as it gets there and checking the value of drtTopAllTempOld.. does it start with data and clear on that first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this;

```
dtTopAllTempOld = dtTopAllTemp();
```

to this;

```
dtTopAllTempOld = dtTopAllTemp.Copy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are assigning `dtTopAllTempOld = dtTopAllTemp;`. Unless we are missing a crucial piece of code, they are the same instance from that point on.

So anything you do with `dtTopAllTemp` after first iteration also happens to `dtTopAllTempOld` (they are literally the same object).